# What options should I set to allow the text field to become a drop-down list inside the Gridview for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-applications, gridview, drop-down-menu

Is it possible? I notice that the Gridview (Visual Studio 2010 Web Application) only contain text field and so was wonder if it is possible to convert or change a text field to a drop down list inside a Gridview.

The text field will appear if you click on the edit field and those text will be store inside a text field.

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC90936.gif))</sub>

Comment: What text field? What grid view?

Comment: @SimpleCoder I have edit the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an edit template to your aspx.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="EmployeeID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeID" HeaderText="EmployeeID" 
                    InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="EmployeeID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" 
                    SortExpression="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" 
                    SortExpression="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HireDate" HeaderText="HireDate" 
                    SortExpression="HireDate" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="City" DataValueField="City" 
                            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("City") %>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("City") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Refer to: [Walkthrough: Displaying a Drop-Down List While Editing in the GridView Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178294%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: The link that you provided is great and useful.